# xmlHttpRequest and returned url

Tags: adobe, air, xmlhttprequest

With help of xmlHttpRequest I make a  server query.
After that the server is redirecting to another page (e.g. "http://site.com/index.html;var=123")

The question is - how can I get full url(side.com/index.html;var...)?

The code is executed with Adobe Air.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean, you are making an xmlHttpRequest inside the HTML control of Adobe Air. AIR provides no functionality on trapping calls originating from the web page that are not a part of the user action. Thus, your AJAX query will move the same way as in a browser. The only luck you may have is with JavaScript to trap the response of the call and use it.

On a side note, you may try loading the same URL with URLLoader/URLStream using a HEAD request in Adobe AIR, with URLRequest.followRedirects set to false. Then listen to HTTPStatusEvent and read the Location response header. HTH.